# Promotion vs. conversion during function overload resolution

Tags: c++, overloading

I am studying function overloading and I have read that promotion takes precedence over conversion. What is promotion and how does it differ from conversion?

For example:

```
void func(int); //function number 1
void func(double); //function number 2
char a;
func(a); // which function will be called, 1 or 2?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone can probably explain this better than me, but I can give example.

Promotions are from types like `char` to `short`, or to `int`, or `long` (etc). Conversions are things like `char` to `double` or `double` to `bool`.

In your example, when calling `func`, there's two options: `func(int)` and `func(double)`. Since `char` to `double` is a conversion, but `char` to `int` is a promotion, then `func(int)` will be called.

I would suggest reading [`[conv]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv) of the standard.